# Download/tagging docker image x86 architecture on M1 mac

Tags: docker

I want to download the x86 image on M1 mac.

```
$docker pull nginx:latest@sha256:b495f952df67472c3598b260f4b2e2ba9b5a8b0af837575cf4369c95c8d8a215
```

It works.

```
$docker images | grep nginx
nginx                          <none>                de2543b9436b   7 days ago    142MB
```

and then I want to tag this

```
$docker tag docker.io/library/nginx:latest 678100228XXX.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/ss-dev-nginx:latest

Error response from daemon: No such image: nginx:latest
```

I am guessing this is because it has the tag not `latest` but `<none>`

I am downloading nginx:latest though, why does this happen?

And how can I tag this?

Comment: The `<none>` is afaik created when an older latest image is updated but still kept in your repo.

Comment: I see.. but I think I downloaded `docker pull nginx:latest@sha256:b495f952df67472c3598b260f4b2e2ba9b5a8b0af837575cf4369c95c8d8a215` latest version,, it's not true?